# How to return JSON by default with Silverstripe Controller?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We have a class that extends `\PageController` & has an `allowed action` to return JSON. Here's some example code:

```
class CustomController extends PageController
{
  private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'json'
  );

  public function json(HTTPRequest $request)
  {
    $data['ID'] = $this->ID;
    $data['Title'] = $this->Title;
    $data['Content'] = $this->Content;
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

When `https://www.example.com/custom/json` is called it returns a JSON object containing some of the page information.

What is the best way to have this Controller return JSON by default?

In the above example we want`https://www.example.com/custom` to return a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out all I needed to do was change the method name from `json` to `index`:

```
public function index(HTTPRequest $request)
{
  $data['ID'] = $this->ID;
  $data['Title'] = $this->Title;
  $data['Content'] = $this->Content;
  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return json_encode($data);
}
```